# ASP.NET Authentication To LDAp

Tags: asp.net, architecture, ldap

We have a web site that we have moved to LDAP authentication. But we are getting many "server not available" LDAP errors, even though the LDAP server remains in service. Do I need to worry about multiple users, each in their own thread causing concurrent authentication requests to the LDAP server and or causing too much authentication traffic for the LDAP server?. Does an (OSI) application accept multiple connections on the same incoming port at the same time or does it have to process them sequentially? Does it accept multiple connections from the same client (my web server) at the same time? If either of these are concerns, how do I architect my solution to overcome them? Should I be creating an single authentication object that is attached to the application object? Or is it o.k. to create it in each individual session/thread?

Comment: Show us how you contact your LDAP to verify the users! Cannot really tell much as long as we don't see what you do and how you do it.... LDAP should be able to handle tens of thousands of concurrent users....

Comment: Do you use Active Directory or another LDAP implementation? What's installed on the computers in your LDAP domain: Windows only or a mix of Win/Lin/Mac?

Comment: We're using an LDAP service of our EMAIL System, a product not well known called FirstClass.  I do suspect the server, the directory entry class won't work , only the LDAP protocol classs. But in IT, if I am going to say it's the LDAP server (run by a different org), I have to show why I think that. Which is why I am here. We were using a static class for the connection, I know that can cause problems, so we changed to a non static.  We just made that change yesterday, and so we are watching it.

Comment: Here's the code we're using:
using (LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection(ldapPath))
                {
                    ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
                    ldap.Bind(new NetworkCredential(userName, password)); 
                }

Comment: Changing to the non- static class has not improved things. I am still getting 10-20 server not available errors every day. My load when fully deployed will be 20 times what it is now.

Comment: We bought a third party component, for this and other reasons, and this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The FirstClass email system can provide LDAP services on port 389 out the 'front' of the application, and out the back, it can retrieve data from a different LDAP server.

What I would suggest is find out if there is a back end LDAP server and ask for permission to use that directly instead of proxying through FirstClass.

Man its been a while since I last saw FirstClass!  Good to see they are still around!